# Clearing an array of 'empty' elements

Tags: php, arrays

I've got the following text :

```
NOTEU START

#Line1  #

#Line2  #

#Line3  #

#Line4  #

NOTEU END
```

I explode the text at every pound sign:

```
$noteText = explode("#", $message);
```

Producing an array :

```
  ( [0] => [1] => Line1 [2] => [3] => Line2 [4] => [5] => Line3 [6] => [7] => Line4 [8] => )
```

I get empty elements in the array which represent the spaces between two consecutive pound signs.

My end goal is to split each line (text inside pound signs) into an array.

This can be achieved by removing these empty array elements however I can't seem to remove them, I've tried :

```
print_r(array_filter($noteText));

foreach($noteText as $key => $val) {
   if ($val == "") unset($noteText[$key]);
}
```

Which has no effect on removing these empty spaces.

Comment: I'd go with regular expressions, as Gal suggests; a simple `preg_match_all("/#(?P<lines>.*)#/", $input, $result);` seems to give the right result (in `$result['lines'])`) for your input...

Answer (score 2):

Try using a combination of [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), and [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove white spaces and then remove empty elements.

```
$nodetext= array_filter(array_map("trim", $nodetext));
```

Using `array_map()` and `trim()` together will take the elements that are just white space and turn them into empty strings. `array_filter()` without a callback will remove empty array values from an array.

Comment: Yes!! That's exactly the answer I was looking for, I knew array_filter and knew there was while space but you put that together with trim. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Usually lines are seperated by \r\n [windows] \n [linux] or \r [mac] so you could use it.
if the lines arent formatted with those line breaks you could easily explode it using regular expressions -

```
$text ="
#Line1  #

#Line2  #

#Line3  #

#Line4  #
";
preg_match_all("!\#(.*)  #!",$text,$matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Comment: A single `\r` hasn't been used on Macs for decades; OS X is BSD-derived and uses `\n` like other unix variants.

Comment: Thanks Matt,not really a mac fan (: